# Tensorflow, how to ensure that everything runs purely in the GPU?

Tags: tensorflow

My understanding is that tensorflow will take a computation graph and run it on both the gpu and cpu to max usage. How can I ensure that my code runs on the gpu only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap all of your graph-building code in a [`tf.device()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/device) block, as follows:

```
with tf.device("/gpu:0"):
    # [Build graph in here.]
```

With this annotation, the placement algorithm will place all operations on the GPU device, and fail if any operations do not have a GPU implementation. (Without this annotation, as you mentioned, it will fall back to placing operations without a GPU implementation on the CPU device.)

Comment: So if I don't use `with tf.device(...)` to manually allocate tensorflow code to different gpus, it seems to *still* use all gpus. Does that mean by default tensorflow distributes a computation graph over all gpus?

Comment: Does it work if i don't have NVEDIA card, as tensor flow  only supports NVIDIA. What if i have Intel Card? Is it possible?